# Ensuring type safety without variants

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following classes:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
 public:
  A(B<T> b) : b_(b) { }

  T foo() {
    return b_.foo();
  }
 private:
  class B<T> b_;
}

template typename<T>
class B {
 public:
  T foo();
}
```

This nicely enforces typing across the stack (you can keep adding more layers and type them on a single type. However, I would like to have two different options on layer two:

```
template <typename T, typename Y>
class A {
 public:
  T foo() {
    return b_.foo();
  }
  Y foo() {
    return c_.foo();
  }

 private:
  class B<T> b;
  class C<Y> c;

}

template typename<T>
class B {
 public:
  T foo();
}

template typename<T>
class C {
 public:
  T foo();
}
```

Is there some way I could templetize the class with multiple typenames and achieve these scheme? Mind, in some situations `T` and `Y` might be the same, so there must be some more differentiations (for example `B<T>` vs `C<Y>`).

I believe I could have multiple functions foo1 and foo2 returning different values. However, I am looking for extensible solution where the customers can provide their own typenames and potentially more than two. Ideally, there would be a single overload (maybe taking identity of the internal class?)

Comment: Polymorphy doesn't work for equally named functions if the only difference is the return type. However, for cases where `T` == `Y`, you may think about template specialization or [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to handle this.

Comment: Even if T=Y, what would `T t = a.foo();`  do? (If T != Y, you can return a proxy with two conversions.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. I was thinking about allowing passing the type identity into different polymorphic functions. Would that work?

Comment: Isn't it easier to pass the varia as reference than use as return ?

Comment: This isn't a bad idea, but still suffers from the problem that T and Y might be the same type, but mean different things.

Comment: @gruszczy: Your code is decidedly confused. In one place, you use `B` as a typename: `A(B bar)`. But in another, you use `B` as a template name: `B<T>`. `B` can't be both, so which is it? Also, what is the relationship between `B` and the template `Bar`? And why are there a number of spurious `class`es in various locations?

Comment: @NicolBolas I clarifed the snippets to use single classes. I am not sure what you mean by spurious classes. This is a simplified example that reflects the code.

Comment: @gruszczy: "*I am not sure what you mean by spurious classes.*" What I mean is this: `class B<T> b_;`. The keyword "class" here is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: It's also not entirely clear what exactly you want. I mean, I get that you want some number of `A::foo` functions, each of which returns the result of forwarding to one of the subobjects of the class. What I want to know is how you are supposed to pick which subobject to forward to? How is the *caller* of `foo` expected to select which overload to call? If your answer is "it depends on how they use the result of the call", then the answer is "that's not how C++ works".

Comment: Hey @gruszczy, your question really looks unclear. Can you add some short example of potential usage? Actually you able to have functions with the same name but returning different types, using `std::enable_if`. But I can't tell you exact way without a sample with your expectations.

Comment: Assuming that this is not an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I would suggest you to put a proper compiling example for what you already have and then put the requirement in a minimal example of what you want. Otherwise this high bounty may go waste due to lack of explanation and clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is hard to understand, but I think you mean to take a list of `template<typename> typename`s and an equal number of `typename`s and construct the product of their zipped application?

```
// wrap a template<typename> typename into a normal type
// e.g. index_of_v<std::vector, std::vector> fails, but
// index_of_v<suspend<std::vector>, suspend<std::vector>> gives 0
template<template<typename> typename>
struct suspend { };
// search for X in Xs and produce a static constexpr std::size_t member values containing the index
// This is just the natural functional programming way to search a linked list
// indexOf(x, Nil) = undefined
// indexOf(x, Cons(y, xs)) = x == y ? 0 : 1 + indexOf(x, xs)
// deriving from std::integral_constant is really just noise;
// could be replaced with an explicit member definition
// but it's considered idiomatic to do this for some reason that I've forgotten
template<typename X, typename... Xs>
struct index_of { }; // base case, the default template only fires when Xs is empty, so the index is undefined 
template<typename X, typename... Xs>
struct index_of<X, X, Xs...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> { }; // if X is at the top of the list, it has index 0
template<typename X, typename Y, typename... Xs>
struct index_of<X, Y, Xs...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, index_of<X, Xs...>::value + 1> { }; // if it isn't, find it's index relative to the tail of the list, then shift it to be the index relative to the whole
// instead of writing index_of<X, Xs..>::value, write index_of_v<X, Xs...>
// this is a convention that you see in the standard library
template<typename X, typename... Xs>
inline constexpr std::size_t index_of_v = index_of<X, Xs...>::value;

// a class cannot have two lists of variadic template parameters
// the easiest thing to do is split the templating into two stages
// the outer template, choices, takes a list of templates as parameters
// template<typename T> class std::vector;
// int is a "base" type, so you can pass int to std::vector<int>
// but std::vector is not like int: std::vector<std::vector> is meaningless
// std::vector alone is just a template<typename> typename
// a function from types to types
template<template<typename> typename... Cs>
struct choices {
    // 2nd "stage" takes the list of "normal" types
    template<typename... Ts>
    class type {
        // apply each template to the corresponding base type
        // the resulting list of base types is passed to std::tuple
        // there's a "field" for each Cs<Ts> inside the tuple
        std::tuple<Cs<Ts>...> parts;

        public:
        // hopefully self-explanatory
        type(Cs<Ts>... parts) : parts(parts...) { }

        // return the result of calling foo() on the container identified by C
        template<template<typename> typename C>
        auto foo() {
            // we know the list of all the Cs,
            // so just find the index of C in it and pass that to std::get
            // then pass in parts to get the desired object, then call foo()
            return std::get<index_of_v<suspend<C>, suspend<Cs>...>>(parts).foo();
        }
    };

    // there's no luck for deducing Cs, since in order to *get* to types we need to specify Cs
    // (choices::type is not a thing, you always write choices<Cs...>::type)
    // But you can deduce `Ts`, by looking at the things contained in each container
    // so, deduction guide
    template<typename... Ts>
    type(Cs<Ts>...) -> type<Ts...>;
};
```

There's nothing particularly interesting going on here. You have a list of container templates, and a list of contained types, and each object contains a tuple of objects of the desired types. *Something* has to be passed to `foo` so it knows which object to retrieve; the sanest option is the type of the container. You could also use the contained type, but apparently those aren't unique, so that wouldn't really work. You could also just pass the index directly. Since we don't know the whole type of the object, there's an auxiliary `index_of` type function to find the necessary index to pass to `std::get`. For simplicity, `index_of` only takes `typename` arguments. Since we want to search for a `template<typename> typename` in a list of such, all of them are wrapped in `suspend` to make it work.

You recover your two `A` types like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct B {
    T x;
    B(T x) : x(x) { }
    T foo() { return x; }
};
using A1 = choices<B>;
void demonstration1() {
    A1::type a(B(5)); // note the deduction guide at work
    std::cout << "B: " << a.foo<B>() << "\n";
}

template<typename T>
struct C {
    T x;
    C(T x) : x(x) { }
    T foo() { return -x; } // keeping it interesting
};
using A2 = choices<B, C>;
void demonstration2() {
    A2::type a(B('a'), C(5));
    std::cout << "B: " << a.foo<B>() << "; C: " << a.foo<C>() << "\n";
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxEAGZXpAA6oFhdbT1DE0FvXzU6Kxt7IycXd0VlTFV/BgJmYgJA41NOBJVw2lT0gki7R2c3XIU0jKzgqpqS6zKYitdOAEpFVANiZA4AcilXa2RDLABqcVcdZGr0LCpp7HEABgBBYdHxzCmZ9WriTGYjZbXNyRHaMYNJ6Z0CA092M42t6529h4BPT0wAfQIxGYhAUr02GwImCMz2YUPuUJhwnhMwIvy0J0wywmaL%2BtEx4MOBlUEwUBgUePQUwA7NIaQARaaySHQ2Eon54zETAAapBx6PxRkwADpRTywa4VhsiSTrFgAB7/VBUGl08TUxmuZnrRFsrGogVc3n8zlC0XC8WEoHEggTOWYRXK%2B7Gl0Kc3YkCkgjoEAgaxQ4DA1j/NC0aoiAj3ea%2B3wALwBBD5q2x6rVGqZ511yP1HIxQp5fNxed2AE1C4azWLuRKpesZbb7Y6ljNjWXxe7JRNPdG/fRMIG2CG6OH6FHvTG8PHAXzG0rmzpXR3sL6AG5sAy7OQTTgp2kMjMspFwnNFwW7Y2nzHmy2S87WVjNCah6oOzzEL0%2BkBxhN27QOuf/Cuez0r%2BCpzs6fLVkuq7rvq2qZqy2YIohx4IhW%2BrYCaxbXjoNbnPWT4IKgeD9AoqrnBMlE4ih7KXpWFoACp4RsVFPsIChkUW5EsaxVE9o8zw5rh9xMcsS4TJ4xQSvBPG8RJBgOA%2ByAgBRclYRAwkzKJkrXpJGQKB0XYSVJEB6QQbqioZqb7m8sm8VmqGojRJ7odidG7Do4JqRMzAGEQEw0KgEBWbSqneZRRyPMQtAfr6wCYJG%2Bx/k2gFRuSlL3J5kp8mSFLmJlNZLssplSR0wqBcFB7rN56qMnZtVVaxDm0eh17abWTXohpEo6O15qGQAtG56IiRZwpnFq5wNZNtk6s5aGmrsDFWsQNoTGm2qsQxEzyo1VHSBA23yoZnryhAx2qjZ1VUdtFUhXSkW9DFu1ald03auS1jABM6ycMBhHEaR9yyLeM3rCuxFUlgRjDkCcL%2BJwwXcddlG/b6XHMBAB0AKwdB0e2UT2aB%2BV89xTJIMielIkikzMPnlagqDA8VVkzGT1PiNjOi0BzYMNbNzUuYtEzLbe0rWiSOjI1tO0ExMOiHTtJ07ed91XTLd2XY90UTANL1piBAD0hsTAA1pgmCeF9doNn2RzVF9U3pmDn2iD9NPTCByBESRmA9fI8sTdqEN4FD0Kw8CBSSEjqZhe76Poj5WMQGAAzMKnXTyxAuP42DrFEz0tr3OzFPSFTFO01LzAM0zMwg9gMds3TvN0jo5ce03Vc15lLOV%2BTkic9zLdO3VELrP6ExGCCtAx6FdnQxH8N0IjuebVRC9hnDUeVXzGoDF0rAgAM2MDKQpgDKsp%2BoEfnkyFuCg9H0m6XJwp8EEfl946QpsgNjqxCEfbgp9z6X1INfAYp8FAgH/u/C%2B%2B9SBwFgEgB0SQ/IkHIJQdIwAFAAAURDKAYERAA7ufV%2BpA0AwjwMifweCbCsEIagEhH9T4UKtuwFwYwRDAAAJyrH/qwqhzgADyfkGFMLgaQFByB1jEGwUfU%2BUjUj4HPqfGg9AmBsA4DwfgghhCiBQHIOQQg8AOCgZALoqBPAFCgQMAa8xPYSDvjITg1JIGP36IIeY1haEEOIaQ%2BBh9j7AOYWAo%2B8oAAcAA2AakTuBsS4RMbhwpVjJImNgeUqCiDvggLgQgJBybtEMrfWQMg37MK/ggY4WAXDBW/r/f%2BgSgFnxCeAyB0DSCwM/gfI%2BkhgkSNaR08pXQVzOF8BobgQA%3D)

Comment: This looks like what I need, but honestly I have problems understanding (I mostly asked because I am not very strong with templates). Would you be so kind and work through individual lines to explain what is their purpose?

Comment: Also, this seems clang specific (at least at the moment), because gcc doesn't like the deduction guidance (I think wrongly). Is there something that allows this for gcc?

Comment: One more comment: this is an amazing feat, but seems to require strong knowledge of templating. Could it be simplified if I removed the need for just a single foo function in choices::type and for unbounded number of arguments?

Comment: I don't think this requires any "strong knowledge."  The only thing that might be considered complicated is `index_of`, but I'd imagine that you'd find it in a library. Yes, if you removed `foo`, then you'd remove the need for `index_of`, which is where the complexity lies. Removing `foo` like that seems to defeat the point, though.

Comment: Not entirely sure how to get GCC to stop being itself. cppreference tells me that deduction guides should work just fine in a class. You could try making a wrapper class of some sort, but then you run into the whole two variadic template parameters packs on one class issue, and I don't think you can name partial specializations for a given set of containers anymore.